# How to run Firebase Admin App with event trigger function in Google Cloud Engine?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-compute-engine

I was unaware before that Cloud Function has big limitation about region. My service deployed under asia-southeast1c (Go-based service with Redis cache at the same region and zone) region, but unfortunately cloud function only available in us-central1. Is there any possibilities to run the function at my Google Compute Engine where my Redis and Service instance exist?

I have try to use VPC but unaware about the region must be in us-central1. I want to implement Cloud Function because it has event-trigger update, which is i want to use to my service, to provide read and write redis cache that supply data to my service. If I pull directly from Firebase, it was time consuming.

This is my code, IP and other information about db and service account are censored due sensitive information.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const bbkey             = "outlet:1:available_vehicles:bluebird"
const   sbkey             = "outlet:1:available_vehicles:silverbird"
Redis = require('ioredis')
var redis = new Redis({
    //sentinels: [{host: "XXX.XX.XX.2", port: "26379"},{host: "XXX.XX.XX.3", port: "26379"}],
    sentinels: [{host: "XXXXX", port: "26379"},{host: "XXXXXXZ", port: "26379"}],
name: "mymaster"
});
redis.ping(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(err)
});

redis.on("error",function(err){
    console.log("ERROR! "+err);
});


function Counter (fleetname,serviceType,location,status){

        if(serviceType===bbkey&&location==="1:PERIMETER BANDARA"){
            date = new Date().getTime();
            if(status<=0){
                console.log(fleetname+" from Bxxxxxx are inbound pool at "+date);
                redis.rpush(bbkey,fleetname);
            }
            if(status>0){
                console.log(fleetname+" from Bxxxxxx are outbound pool at "+date);
                redis.lrem(bbkey,0,fleetname);
            }
            if(serviceType===sbkey&&location==="1:PERIMETER BANDARA"){
                date = new Date().getTime();
            if(status<=0){
                console.log(fleetname+" from Sxxxxxx are inbound pool at "+date);
                redis.rpush(sbkey,fleetname)
            }
            if(status>0){
                console.log(fleetname+" from Sxxxxxx are outbound pool at "+date);
                redis.lrem(sbkey,0,fleetname)
            }
        }
        }
}
exports.counterTaxi = 
functions.database.ref('/airport/{type}/vehicles/{no}/position')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
    console.log('Counting', context.params.no);
    const position = change.after.val();
        return Counter(context.params.no,context.params.type,position.content.location,position.content.time_out)
})
;
```

Comment: Cloud Functions is available in many regions.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations

Comment: but not in my region, asia-southeast1c , https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

Comment: Actually the problem is my cloud function provide update (r and w data) to my redis instance at different area. VPC is still beta and limited, so no option if i try it, But if there's a chance to operate the function as regular apps (not cloud one) under the Compute engine where my redis exist, its very preferable. Redis can help me to cut time to get all data to get all data from Firebase.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what are you trying to achieve. What do you mean by running your GCF at your GCE instance? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Okay i try to clarify. So there're some limitation of Google Cloud Function about regions and zone. My GCE instance run in different region as my GCF instance. My GCE Instance has Redis instance exist, so the target is I can cache my Firebase queries result and store it to redis. When there're some change on firebase database (new car inbound or outbound), I will update the redis GCF EventListener ability. I realise if I can place GCF-like EventListener function for my Firebase at my GCE instance.

Comment: I recommend you to set up a Serverless VPC Access connector in a region that is allowed by GCF and establishing a connection to the GCE instance. You can find more information here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc#connecting_to_your_vpc_network and here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#connectors

Comment: Thank you Maxim for the suggestion to use VPC. But it still beta and I'm not sure if my region are ready to use Serverless VPC.

Comment: UPDATE: after some tweaks, the functions can connect normally and send some to my redis instance